# MongoDB data search result

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I did a search data using mongodb and get results, but I have trouble when they want to get the data into list. My data :

http://pastebin.com/VLRhsZP9

I have tried using :

```
foreach($data as $doc) {
    echo $doc['nama']."<br>";
}
```

But there is an error `Undefined index: nama`

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is the `$data` var, your foreach could be something like:

```
foreach($data as $key => $doc) {
    echo $doc['obj']['nama']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Error : Undefined index: obj

Comment: @BerthoJoris what you posted is `$data` ?